# Supremum of the image of a monotonic function

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

For a monotonic function $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ where $D\subset\mathbb{R}$, and two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $\sup A=\sup B$, is it true that $\sup f(A)=\sup f(B)$, where $f(A)$ denotes the image of set $A$ under function $f$? If so, how to prove it, assuming $f(\sup A)$ and $f(\sup B)$ may be undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This need not be true. The function may be monotonic but it may be decreasing. e.g. y= -x and choose  D= [0,1] A =[1/2, 1] B=[1/3, 1] then Sup(A)=Sup(B)=1  and next thing is reversed. Right?

Comment: What if $f$ is monotonically increasing?

Comment: @YutongZhang Still no: take $A = (0,1)$, $B = [0,1]$, and take $$f: x \mapsto \left\{\array{x&x< 1\\x+1&x \geq 1}\right..$$ Then $\sup f(A) = 1$, but $\sup f(B) = 2$.

Comment: For proving something we need proof. And to disprove things even counter example is sufficient.

Comment: But I'll write for increasing as well....

Comment: @RaviSatpute What condition on $f$ should I add to make this conclusion hold? Perhaps continuity?

Comment: Only continuity won't be sufficient. As my counter example is also continuous. But if $f$ is from [a,b] continuous and increasing then these are sufficient conditions and much stronger. I'm intentionally adding these conditions so that you won't have to worry about boundary points. You can also try with A and B finite sets and keeping Sup included. So that the functions behaviour on in between points will matter and sup f(A) you can try with curves.